# MySQL client history not logging some queries

Tags: mysql

I have noticed that quite recently the `mysql` client tool is not logging all queries I issue. The behaviour seems to be very inconsistent; some queries are logged and others are not, without any definite pattern, although it seems the simpler the query, the more likely it is to be logged. This is annoying to say the least. I am using MySQL 5.6.14 under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

There really doesn't seem to be much of a pattern: a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_X WHERE COL_1=3;` might well be logged whereas `SELECT COL_1,COUNT(COL_1) FROM TABLE_X GROUP BY COL_1` won't be.

Any ideas? This is a very recent release of MySQL and I'm only using it in development but I want to roll it out to our live machines since the microsecond timestamp resolution solves a number of issues I have in a much cleaner fashion than hitherto.

UPDATE: as per Alex_at_wearenotmachines below, *any* pattern of the form `*PASSWORD*` in the query disables logging, which is clearly an overly-broad criterion.

Answer (score 4):

Just reported this at bugs.mysql.com - are you getting the weird mysql> prompt suddenly appears in the middle of the command thing as well? And the average of about .75 seconds to run create table commands? seems a little slow....

Can't see any pattern either - it refused to remember SELECT password FROM users, ever. but remembered most other things. Have been using for about 3 weeks and just noticed today but going back through my history I can see kind of logical gaps where stuff is evidently missing.

Comment: NOT A BUG! MySQL came back saying:
Please note that statements are ignored and not logged if they match
any pattern in the “ignore” list i.e By default, the pattern list
is "*IDENTIFIED*:*PASSWORD*", to ignore statements that refer to
passwords.

Please reference -
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-logging.html

Not sure if that helps sort yours out....  full bug report here:
http://bugs.mysql.com/?id=71987

Comment: This appears to be what's happening (I don't know how I missed it.) Can you amend your answer so I can choose it as best? I really wish there were a way of completely disabling this behaviour instead of simply adding extra patterns to the stop list.

Answer (score 4):

This really is a bug.  There is no reason to remove it from the current in client history.  It should be available to the person who just typed it!

Also, the patterns are overly broad.  If there is no string literal, there is no sensitive data, so the patterns, rather than "*IDENTIFIED*:*PASSWORD*" should require a string literal somewhere in the line (still too broad but more reasonable) like:   *IDENTIFIED*['"`]*:*PASSWORD*['"`]*

Additionally you should be able to override these patterns (like I've been writing multi table joins on password columns (don't ask) and I can't even up arrow to put in a missing comma...)

One more things (Thank you Brian Matthews! http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,631456,631456#msg-631456) if you are completely ham strung by this like I am, you can disable it by hexediting the mysql client binary.  Ugly, but effective.  I now have a script called fix_mysql_client...

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78088  a bug requesting that this be changed to still be secure but to be much much less painful.

Comment: Thanks. This really is a brain-dead behaviour. It means, for example, you can't even use the history to bring back a line if, for example, you're creating a table with `PASSWORDx` in one of the columns. That's dumb.

Comment: Nobody should second-guess the user.  During a breach, seconds count, and having to retype or use a clipboard is clumsy and painful.  So there is a value for additional keywords? Being open source the base list must be somewhere, frobbed or ROT13'd or BASE64'd to make it harder to seach for, but it must be there in the "client" source.

In the meantime - put these queries in bash scripts or embed them in code since they  would be re-usable.